# Como retornar o tamanho de um resultado de uma variável?

Tags: javascript

Pessoal eu criei uma função a qual com ela estou retornando a quantidade de notas obtidas(no caso 6 notas), também retorno uma lista das notas que bateu o recorde(o recorde era a nota 8) e também estou retornando a pior nota (a nota 4). Portanto gostaria de saber como retorno a quantidade de notas que bateu o recorde, como podem ver no código abaixo eu apenas conseguir listar essas notas, portanto não sei como pegar o `length` da constante `total`.

```
function notas() {
const pontos = ["4", "8", "6.3", "9", "9.5", "8.5"];
const quanti = pontos.length;
console.log("Foram obtidas " + quanti + " notas no total!");
console.log("Apenas as notas abaixo superaram o recorde:");

for (let i = 0; i < pontos.length; i++) {
    const total = pontos[i];
    if (total > 8) {
        console.log(total);
    }
}
console.log("Abaixo a nota mais ruim: ")
var min = pontos.map(Number).reduce(function (a, b) {
    return Math.min(a, b);
});

console.log(min);
return notas;
}

    notas();
```

Comment: Seria `total.length`? Já que todas são string.

Comment: vc pode colocar um contador dentro do `if (total > 8)` que conta quantas vezes entrou lá

Comment: o length acho que não funciona pq não é uma lista, voce pode criar uma lista de notsa maiores que o record e usar lista.push(pontos[i]), e depois ver o length dessa lista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variável `const total` está servindo apenas para armazenar temporariamente o valor de cada posição da array para ser comparado ao valor `8`, portanto essa variável não está armazenando todos os valores que são maiores que `8`. Logo ela não serve para contar quantas notas são maiores que `8`, pois seu valor final será o da última iteração do laço `for`.

O que você precisa fazer é criar uma outra variável com valor `0`:

```
let bateram_o_recorde = 0;
```

E ir incrementando cada vez que a condição `total > 8` for atendida:

```
bateram_o_recorde++;
```

No final essa variável terá o valor de quantos números foram maiores do que `8`:

```js
function notas() {
   const pontos = ["4", "8", "6.3", "9", "9.5", "8.5"];
   const quanti = pontos.length;
   console.log("Foram obtidas " + quanti + " notas no total!");
   console.log("Apenas as notas abaixo superaram o recorde:");
   
   let bateram_o_recorde = 0;
   for (let i = 0; i < pontos.length; i++) {
    const total = pontos[i];
    if (total > 8) {
        console.log(total);
        bateram_o_recorde++;
    }
   }
   console.log("Abaixo a nota mais ruim: ")
   var min = pontos.map(Number).reduce(function (a, b) {
    return Math.min(a, b);
   });
   
   console.log(min);
   console.log("Quantidade de notas que bateram o record: ", bateram_o_recorde);
   return notas;
}

notas();
```

> Só não entendi a linha final `return notas;`, já que `notas` é a própria
>   função.

---

Se você está querendo armazenar as notas maiores que `8`, teria que criar uma array, fazer um `.push(total)` e depois fazer um `.length` nessa array:

```js
function notas() {
   const pontos = ["4", "8", "6.3", "9", "9.5", "8.5"];
   const quanti = pontos.length;
   console.log("Foram obtidas " + quanti + " notas no total!");
   console.log("Apenas as notas abaixo superaram o recorde:");
   
   let bateram_o_recorde = []; // cria a array
   for (let i = 0; i < pontos.length; i++) {
    const total = pontos[i];
    if (total > 8) {
        console.log(total);
        bateram_o_recorde.push(total); // insere na array
    }
   }
   console.log("Abaixo a nota mais ruim: ")
   var min = pontos.map(Number).reduce(function (a, b) {
    return Math.min(a, b);
   });
   
   console.log(min);
   console.log("Quantidade que bateram o record: ", bateram_o_recorde.length); // conta os itens da array
   return notas;
}

notas();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, cara como não pensei nisso! Obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 2):

**Para aqueles que gostam de soluções em uma linha**

---

> Gostaria de saber como retorno a quantidade de notas que bateu o
>   recorde [...]

Você pode usar a função filter para retornar os registros de notas que correspondem ao filtro e então usar o length para retornar a quantidade desses registros, então basicamente esse seria seu método

```
pontos.filter(x => parseFloat(x) > 8).length;
```

No seu código ficaria assim:

```js
function notas() {
const pontos = ["4", "8", "6.3", "9", "9.5", "8.5"];
const quanti = pontos.length;
console.log("Foram obtidas " + quanti + " notas no total!");
console.log("Apenas as notas abaixo superaram o recorde:");

for (let i = 0; i < pontos.length; i++) {
    const total = pontos[i];
    if (total > 8) {
        console.log(total);
    }
}

console.log('Abaixo o número de notas que superaram o recorde');
console.log(pontos.filter(x => parseFloat(x) > 8).length);

console.log("Abaixo a menor nota: ")
var min = pontos.map(Number).reduce(function (a, b) {
    return Math.min(a, b);
});

console.log(min);
return notas;
}

    notas();
```

Comment: Legal, dessa forma ai nunca tinha feito, obrigado!